# VPN between static IP address and dynamic and under NAT IP address

Tags: vpn, nat, dynamic-ip

I have to connect two network like that:

```
RemoteLan<-->Router3G/Firewall<-->INTERNET<-->Firewall<-->LocalLan
```

So, I need to reach a device inside the RemoteLan from LocalLan. The firewall has a static IP address and also is the VPN server (OpenVPN or IPsec), but the remote 3G router has a dynamic and under NAT IP address.
The remote router also is a firewall and can initiate the Open VPN connection.

Is this system technically feasible and can I reach the remote device?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to expand on your question a bit, as what you can do, depends on the router/firewall and device OS and current configs

Comment: Yes, I know it. I prefered to stay general because I don't care what type of devices I use. I only need to know if it is fesible using Openvpn or IPsec. In any case, I will try to do it with two watchguard firewall, or one watchguard in the local position and one VPN enabled 3G router in the remote position.